# React class update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Something like:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <MenuElem isSelected={false} />
        <MenuElem isSelected={true} />
        );
    }
}
class MenuElem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li onClick={() => this.setState({isSelected: true})} className={this.props.isSelected ? "is-active" : ""}>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Why the isSelected props dont update when I fire the click event ?
How can i add the "is-active" class when I click ?

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: No, just the isSelected props just stays false

Comment: With the chrome react tool, I can see the state "isSelected" set to true but the props stay false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `props` and `state` together in your logic.

- `props` are external parameters that a component receives from its
  parent.   They are read only and can't be changed by the child.
- `state` is a local object that gets updated. local in a way that only
  the very same component "knows" about it.

In your example, you are passing a Boolean `isSelected` from a parent to a child, then inside the child's (`MenuElem`) `onClick` event you are creating a local Boolean `isSelected` (inside the local state object) but when you conditionally passing the `CSS` style you are checking the `prop` `isSelected` passed via the parent, which will can't changed by the child as it is a read only property.

You can either check the `this.state.isSelected` or just pass an updated `props.isSelected` from the parent. The second choice will mean you need to manage the state at the parent level.

Small example for local state inside the child:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MenuElem />
    );
  }
}
class MenuElem extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isSelected: false
  }

  render() {
    const { isSelected } = this.state;
    return (
      <li onClick={() => this.setState({ isSelected: true })} style={{ color: isSelected ? 'green': 'initial'  }}>
        item
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Example for parent state, note that it is advice to keep track for the id's so you can signal the parent which child was being clicked:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: 'item 1', selected: false },
      { id: 2, name: 'item 2', selected: true }]
  }

  onItemClick = itemId => {
    this.setState(prev => {
      const nextItems = prev.items.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          selected: item.id === itemId
        }
      });
      return { items: nextItems };
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          items.map(item => (
            <MenuElem
              key={item.id}
              {...item}
              onClick={this.onItemClick}
            />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class MenuElem extends React.Component {

  onClick = () => {
    const { onClick, id } = this.props;
    onClick(id);
  }

  render() {
    const { selected, name } = this.props;
    return (
      <li
        onClick={this.onClick}
        style={{ color: selected ? 'green' : 'initial' }}>
        {name}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but ,How if i need to do this : 
```<MenuElem isSelected={false} />
<MenuElem isSelected={true} />``` ?

Comment: Ok my bad i can just do ```isSelected: this.props.isSelected``` Thanks for you answer

Comment: In MenuElem constructor use `this.state = { isSelected: props. isSelected }`  but I think You are doing something wrong :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've added another example for parent state (with multiple `MenuElem` of course)

Answer (score 1):

`props` and `state` are different things. Your `MenuElem` component know about `isSelected` as `props`, not `state`. So no `setState` for the guy. Two options:

1) `isSelected` is in state in `Parent` component and you pass it as props to `MenuElem` among a callback to do the `setState` (but the state belongs to `Parent`)

2) `Parent` stays the same and you assign `isSelected` to state for `MenuElem` (then you can do a `setState`, and in this case the state is in `MenuElem`)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your script by making sure `MenuElem` is statefull, in this way you can set its own internal state based on your event (onClick for instance).

Example:

```
class MenuElem extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isSelected: false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={() => this.setState({ isSelected: true })} style={{ color: isSelected ? 'green': 'initial'  }}>
        item
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you need only props you can do

```
class MenuElem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      const { isSelected } = this.props
      <li onClick={() => this.setState({ isSelected })} style={{ color: isSelected ? 'green': 'initial'  }}>
        item
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my last edit : MenuElem can be 'IsSelected' to true

Comment: Do you need a toggle functionality? So when a user click, you set is Selected from true to false and vice versa?

Comment: Ok my bad i can just do ```isSelected: this.props.isSelected``` Thanks for you answer

Comment: @Hyro you are welcome, please do not forget to accept or up-vote this answer if you found it useful :) thanks!

Comment: My next step is that only one MenuElem  can be set to true, but I have always one selected by default.
Now I'll have to set all the 'isSelected' to false exect the clicked one.
Not sure my approch is the good one

Comment: @Hyro interesting, you should create a new question for that. Please do not forget to up vote answers you found useful if you think it is relevant.